# Android Lock Screen Notification Custom View with Ripple and Double Tap

Tags: android, view, android-notifications, lockscreen, ripple

I am working on an Android app. This last makes use of a notification with a custom view that is displayed on the lock screen. Unfortunately, I am not able to get the ripple and elevation effect when I tap on it like other notifications. Also, a single touch trigger the intent I have configured whereas other notifications require double tap.

I have put a minimal project example on Github:

https://github.com/lpellegr/android-notification-custom-example

The app example offers two buttons to publish notifications: one that uses a custom view and suffer from the issues mentioned above and another notification that uses the default system view with the expected behaviour.

[image]

Any idea about how to get the ripple and elevation effect but also the double tap behaviour (by keeping the custom view) is welcome.

PS: I am targeting API 19+ and I want to use a custom view layout for the notification, along with *setOnClickPendingIntent* since only this listener allows to open an activity whatever the security mode of the device is.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `setOnClickPendingIntent` from the method `publishNotificationWithCustomView` and add `setContentIntent` to the notification builder:

```
private void publishNotificationWithCustomView() {
    String title = "Notification Custom View";
    String content = "No ripple effect, no elevation, single tap trigger";
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(content)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setContentIntent(createLockscreenNotificationPendingIntent(context));

    int notificationLayoutResId = R.layout.lock_screen_notification;

    // using folder layout-vX is having issue with LG devices
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        notificationLayoutResId = R.layout.lock_screen_notification_android_n;
    }

    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), notificationLayoutResId);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, content);

    builder.setCustomContentView(remoteView);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    publishNotification(context, notification, 7);
}
```

Then remove `android:clickable="true"` from `lock_screen_notification.xml` and `lock_screen_notification_android_n.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp">

    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, if I use _setContentIntent_ instead of _setOnClickPendingIntent_, when the device is secured with a schema, pin, etc. the intent requires to unlock the lock screen to see the activity. When _setOnClickPendingIntent_ is set, the activity opens without unlocking, whatever the security mode is. For this reason, your suggestion is not valid to me.

Comment: @Laurent Have you find a solution?

Comment: Still no solutions :X so boring